# When I try to use the read() function on a file in Python, the output is blank

Tags: python

This is the code that I've tried:

```
test = open('test.txt', 'w+')
test.write('test')
print(test.read())
```

I'm using version 3.8.2 of Python on Visual Studio Code.
I'm getting no errors when I run it, but the output is empty.
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Rewind back to the start of the file after writing: `test.seek(0)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the format `'r+'`, and `seek`:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as test:
    test.write('test')
    test.seek(0) # seek lets us from which index we want to start reading
    print(test.read())
```